# Angularjs: when use ng-value, value = 0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-value

I got one weird error.  When I use ng-value, the page render a 'value=0' for some options.  The console doesn't show errors.

Here is the code:

```
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="{{x.make_id}}">{{x.make}}</option>
```

Here is the result:

```
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="acura" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ACURA</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in makes -->
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="alfa-romeo" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="0">ALFA ROMEO</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in makes -->
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="alpina" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ALPINA</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: x in makes -->
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="armstrong-siddeley" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="0">ARMSTRONG SIDDELEY</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind an expression. ngValue uses `$eval` data binding which means you should remove the `{{ }}`

```
<option ng-repeat="x in makes" ng-value="x.make_id">{{x.make}}</option>
```

**Edit:** This isn't documented very well in the AngularJS docs.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer. @zif

Comment: Sorry, how to accept? I'm new to stackoverflow @ThinkingMedia